# jquery datepicker date restriction not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I try to restrict a picker by value from another picker. I looked other questions here but they seem to be outdated and not work

What I do is following

```
<p><input type="text" id="startdatepicker"></p>
<p><input type="text" id="enddatepicker"></p>

$(function() {
    $("#startdatepicker")
        .datepicker({ minDate: -1, maxDate:"" })
        .datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
});

$(function() {
    $("#enddatepicker")
        .datepicker({
            minDate: $("#startdatepicker").datepicker("getDate"), 
            maxDate: ""
        })
        .datepicker("option", "dateFormat", "dd.mm.yy");
});
```

How to do this correctly ?

Comment: Unless you're setting up the second picker after the first one's date is selected, it's not going to work like that. So I would use the the `change` event on the one to call the setting on the other, after the value is picked. Also, I don't see a reason to call `datapicker()` twice, pass the `dateFormat` option in the constructor options like `minDate` and `maxDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly straightforward to accomplish:

```
$(function() {
    $("#startdatepicker, #enddatepicker")
        .datepicker({
            minDate: -1,
            dateFormat: "dd.mm.yy",
         })
     ;

    $('#enddatepicker')
        .datepicker('option', 'disabled', true);

    $('#startdatepicker').on('change', function(){
        var datestamp = this.value.split('.');

        datestamp = new Date(
            +datestamp[2],
            +datestamp[1],
            +datestamp[0]
        );

        if (!datestamp) return false;

        $('#enddatepicker')
            .datepicker('option', 'disabled', false)
            .datepicker('option', 'minDate', datestamp)
        ;
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zvc1p8xk/